# Weird Rails migration / schema.rb issue

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database-schema, rails-migrations

A while back I ran the following migration:

```
class CreatePipelineSpecs < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :pipeline_specs do |t|
      t.integer :id_no
      t.string :od
      t.string :wt
      t.string :material
      t.string :spec_type
      t.string :spec_grade
      t.string :mop
      t.string :stress_level
      t.string :joints
      t.text :notes
      t.string :ip
      t.references :pipeline, index: true, foreign_key: false

      t.timestamps null: false
    end
    add_index :pipeline_specs, :id_no
  end
end
```

I am not sure what has happened now but every time I run `rake db:migrate` the `scheme.rb` file gets updated with:

```
  create_table "pipeline_specs", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.integer  "id_no"
    t.string   "od"
    t.string   "wt"
    t.string   "material"
    t.string   "spec_type"
    t.string   "spec_grade"
    t.string   "mop"
    t.string   "stress_level"
    t.string   "joints"
    t.text     "notes"
    t.string   "ip"
    t.integer  "pipelines_id"
    t.datetime "created_at",   null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   null: false
  end

  add_index "pipeline_specs", ["id_no"], name: "index_pipeline_specs_on_id_no", using: :btree
  add_index "pipeline_specs", ["pipelines_id"], name: "index_pipeline_specs_on_pipelines_id", using: :btree
```

Note the plural **pipelines_id**.  The actual database tables (dev, production etc.) are all **pipeline_id** which is correct as the reference table is `Pipeline`.  So I add a new unrelated migration and the `schema.rb` gets updated and these get changed back to plural again after I change them back.  If I forget to change them when I run tests everything breaks as the wrong schema gets loaded into the test environment.

I am at a loss here.  I am I missing something obvious here or is there some hidden migration schema table etc.

The only think I can this of is when I made the original migration I used `pipelines:references` vs `pipeline:references`, then fixed my mistake, and then cleaned up the migrations before committing this and deploying it.

Any ideas here one why this is happening and how to fix it once and for all?

**UPDATE**

Here are my three related models:

```
irb(main):031:0> Pipeline
=> Pipeline(id: integer, licence: string, company: string, company_id: integer, ba_code: string, substance_code: string, substance: string, h2s: string, partial_pressure: string, notes: text, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, slug: string)
irb(main):032:0> PipelineSpec
=> PipelineSpec(id: integer, id_no: integer, od: string, wt: string, material: string, spec_type: string, spec_grade: string, mop: string, stress_level: string, joints: string, notes: text, ip: string, pipeline_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, slug: string)
irb(main):033:0> PipelineSegment
=> PipelineSegment(id: integer, line: integer, lsd_from: integer, sec_from: integer, twp_from: integer, rge_from: integer, m_from: integer, fc_from: string, lsd_to: integer, sec_to: integer, twp_to: integer, rge_to: integer, m_to: integer, fc_to: string, length: string, aasm_state: string, state_comment: string, state_user_id: integer, aasm_date: datetime, env: string, volume: string, notes: text, pipeline_id: integer, pipeline_spec_id: integer, created_at: datetime, updated_at: datetime, slug: string)
```

`Pipeline` has_many `PipelineSpec` and `PipelineSegment`.  `PipelineSegment` has_one `PipelineSpec`.

**UPDATE 2**

Checked my test environment schema - it's fine.  Ran rake db:migrate and again the `schema.rb` gets updated.  Run the tests again and get gobs of:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid:         ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: PG::UndefinedColumn: ERROR:  column "pipeline_id" of relation "pipeline_specs" does not exist
        LINE 1: ..., "mop", "stress_level", "joints", "notes", "ip", "pipeline_...
                                                                     ^
        : INSERT INTO "pipeline_specs" ("id", "id_no", "od", "wt", "material", "spec_type", "spec_grade", "mop", "stress_level", "joints", "notes", "ip", "pipeline_id", "created_at", "updated_at") VALUES (1, 1, '88.9', '3.18', 'S', 'Z245.1', '359 2', '9930', '25', 'W', 'MyText', 'U', 1, '2017-04-24 03:47:26', '2017-04-24 03:47:26')
```

as the fixtures try to load into the incorrect test schema that was just loaded at test time.

Comment: See if you have any related useless models in your /models/ folder that might cause the issue.

Comment: Nope - all the related models are straight forward and the dev database has `pipeline_id`

Comment: Are you by chance using MySQL?  Also, do you have a version of schema.rb in your SCM from before this migration?

Comment: I am using postgresql

Answer (score 3):

The schema is **[recreated from the actual state](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_migrations.html#what-are-schema-files-for-questionmark) of your database** after each migrations run. So I guess the `pipelines_id` must indeed exist somewhere in your db or at least Rails must think it exists in the db. I would do the following to narrow the issue down:

- Run `rake db:schema:dump SCHEMA=myschema.rb` - this will generate a differently-named schema file manually. This is the same rake task that is also run after the migrations. I expect that the new schema will contain the plural `pipelines_id` column, too.
- Then I'd take a look in the `log/development.log` (or whatever environment you are experiencing the issue in). You should see `SELECT schema_migrations.* FROM schema_migrations` and a bunch of further queries for showing structure of each table in your database there. Find the query that deals with the `pipeline_specs` table and run it manually in the db console to see what you precisely get. My expectation is that you'll either:

  - see the plural `pipelines_ids` there too - that would prove the column indeed exists in the db
  - or not - in which case I would restart everything I could in rails just to be sure there is no caching involved anywhere - specifically I'd restart spring with `spring stop`. Also I'd check (don't know Postgres that well to tell for sure) whether there might be any caching involved on the Postgres side. Then I'd try again.

Answer (score 0):

I think that because the migration you deleted did't run on test environment, try reset the test database by:

```
RAILS_ENV=test rake db:migrate:reset
```

Comment: No luck either.  In the test environment the schema is the same (correct).  See my latest update.

Answer (score 0):

Try to specify a `foregein_key` in model `PipelineSpec` to `pipelines_id`

```
class PipelineSpec < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :pipeline, foreign_key: :pipelines_id
end
```

Comment: I think you are on to something here.  I looked back and I had that commented out and just a plain old `belongs_to :pipeline`.  I will check on my next migration.  I bet I commented it out thinking I was refactoring to eliminate redundant code.

Comment: D'oh!  Nope.  I thought for sure that was going to be it.

Comment: I even have the foreign_key set in pipeline.rb on the other side.